# Using dplyrs group_by and summarise to find number of intersections with a different vector

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I have a situation where I am trying to find the number of intersections with a vector *per group* in another tibble.

**Data example**

```
a <- tibble(EXPERIMENT = rep(c("a","b","c"),each =4), 
            ECOTYPE = rep(1:12))
b <- tibble(ECOTYPE = c(1,1,5,4,8,7,6,1,4,4,2,5,6,7,1))
```

I want to find the number of intersections between `ECOTYPE` in `b` and `ECOTYPE`per `EXPERIMENT` in `a`.

I wonder if I can use dplyr to solve this, as the `group_by` function seems to fit this problem, but when I run:

```
a %>% 
  group_by(EXPERIMENT) %>% 
  summarise(INTERSECTIONS = length(intersect(b$ECOTYPE, .$ECOTYPE))
```

I only get the total number of intersections between `a` and `b`.

Am I missing something?

**Edit:**

Sorry for not posting my desired output. I would like something like this:

`# A tibble: 3 x 2
  EXPERIMENT INTERSECTIONS
       <chr>         <dbl>
1          a             8
2          b             7
3          c             0`

Comment: Your question is perhaps vague, and it would benefit you to post your desired output.

Comment: With reproducible data, good formatting, and now with desired output, what a well-formed first question! Welcome to the site! :)

Answer (score 2):

Depending how you want to count, this will give the number of rows in `b` matching `a`:

```
b %>% mutate(b_flag = 1) %>%
  right_join(a) %>%
  group_by(EXPERIMENT) %>% 
  summarize(INTERSECTIONS = sum(b_flag, na.rm = T))
# # A tibble: 3 x 2
#   EXPERIMENT INTERSECTIONS
#       <fctr>         <dbl>
# 1          a             8
# 2          b             7
# 3          c             0
```

---

I think the only problem with your code is the unnecessary `.$`, but it gives the counts of **distinct** ecotypes in `b`, ignoring the fact that `b` has three `ECOTYPE = 1` rows, for example.

```
a %>% 
  group_by(EXPERIMENT) %>% 
  summarise(INTERSECTIONS = length(intersect(b$ECOTYPE, ECOTYPE)))
# # A tibble: 3 x 2
#   EXPERIMENT INTERSECTIONS
#       <fctr>         <int>
# 1          a             3
# 2          b             4
# 3          c             0
```

This is a result of how `intersect` works:

```
intersect(c(1, 2, 3), c(1, 1, 1))
# [1] 1
```

Comment: Thank you very much for a great answer! I´m so used to always use the `.$`

Comment: You almost never need `.$` inside `dplyr` functions, like `summarise` and `mutate` - they already know what's going on, and more importantly how to work with groups. When you use `.$ECOTYPE`, it's the *whole column* without any group information anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Join the two and count how many are left:

```
inner_join(a,b, by='ECOTYPE') %>% group_by(EXPERIMENT) %>% count()
# A tibble: 2 x 2
# Groups:   EXPERIMENT [2]
  EXPERIMENT     n
       <chr> <int>
1          a     8
2          b     7
```

Now, if you add an indicator column to `b`, you can start to count absences as well:

```
b %>% mutate(present=TRUE) %>% right_join(a, by='ECOTYPE') %>% group_by(EXPERIMENT) %>% summarise(n(), missing=sum(is.na(present)))
# A tibble: 3 x 3
  EXPERIMENT `n()` missing
       <chr> <int>   <int>
1          a     9       1
2          b     7       0
3          c     4       4
```